# theano installation (windows 64bit python 2)

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

I started an installation of theano.

My computer SPEC:
  - OS           : Windows 7 64bit
  - Graphic card : NVIDIA Geforce GT 630
  - CPU          : AMD FX-8120

I installed theano by installation guide of deeplearning.net .
(http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#configure-theano-for-gpu-use)

I successfully finished installation process under.

Visual Studio 2010 -> Windows Software Development Kit version 7.1 -> CUDA -> Microsoft Visual C++ Complier for Python 2.7 (adding header) -> TDM GCC -> WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4 -> env.bat -> Theano setup

When I create a test file(under) and test it, it successfully execute.

-------test file----------------------------------

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano
A = np.random.rand(1000,10000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
B = np.random.rand(10000,1000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
np_start = time.time()
AB = A.dot(B)
np_end = time.time()
X,Y = theano.tensor.matrices('XY')
mf = theano.function([X,Y],X.dot(Y))
t_start = time.time()
tAB = mf(A,B)
t_end = time.time()
print "NP time: %f[s], theano time: %f[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)" %(np_end-np_start, t_end-t_start)
print "Result difference: %f" % (np.abs(AB-tAB).max(), )
```

---

**BUT when I add .theanorc.txt** 
---.theanorc.txt--------------------------------

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[nvcc]
flags = --use-local-env  --cl-version=2008
```

---

It gives me an error like this(under)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjspcpaz4hkeep8/11.PNG?dl=0

I have no problem with CUDA-devicequery & nvidia-smi.exe

-------------------------DeviceQuery--------------------------

```
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v7.0\1_Utilities\deviceQuery\../../bin/win64/Debug/deviceQuery.exe Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GT 630"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.0 / 7.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 512 MBytes (536870912 bytes)
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, ( 48) CUDA Cores/MP:     96 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1620 MHz (1.62 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1600 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 131072 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535),
3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GT 630
Result = PASS
```

-------------------------nvidia-smi.exe--------------------------

```
Thu May 07 20:21:50 2015
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 347.62     Driver Version: 347.62         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 630     WDDM  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 50%   31C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    476MiB /   511MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage          |
|=============================================================================|
|    0              C   Not Supported                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please help me..

Comment: I changed my file ".theanorc.txt" to ".theanorc" . Thank you .                                      But still it has an error that "No CUDA DEVICE DETECTED".

Answer (score 0):

You should use  a ".theanorc" file, not a ".theanorc.txt".

You may also write your question on the theano-users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theano-users

Next Winpython release will include theano+mingwpy, so it may the reduce complexity of setup.

Comment: Do you mean just ".theanorc"?    It didn't work....      I just put ".theanorc.txt" file in winpython/setting folder...

Comment: Actually, the official Theano documentation states that you can use either ".theanorc" or ".theanorc.txt", which it states is "to make Windows users’ life easier" http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html